# Correcting the value of a column based on another value with dplyr, for every ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with person_ID, Job_ID, Municipality_code, and some other variables (see sample dataframe below). The Job_ID variable is measured on a monthly basis, the Municipality_code on a yearly basis.

```
 as.data.frame(df)
   Person_ID Month Year Job_ID Municipality_code
1          1     1 2017   Job1                 1
2          1     2 2017   Job1                 1
3          1     3 2017   Job1                 1
4          1     4 2017   Job1                 1
5          1     5 2017   Job2                 1
6          1     6 2017   Job2                 1
7          1     7 2017   Job2                 1
8          1     8 2017   Job2                 1
9          1     9 2017   Job2                 1
10         1    10 2017   Job2                 1
11         1    11 2017   Job2                 1
12         1    12 2017   Job2                 1
13         1     1 2018   Job2                20
14         1     2 2018   Job2                20
15         1     3 2018   Job2                20
16         1     4 2018   Job2                20
17         1     5 2018   Job2                20
18         1     6 2018   Job2                20
19         1     7 2018   Job2                20
20         1     8 2018   Job2                20
21         1     9 2018   Job2                20
22         1    10 2018   Job2                20
23         1    11 2018   Job2                20
24         1    12 2018   Job2                20
```

I want to correct the Municipality_code for each Person_ID based on their Job_ID. For example: we notice that Person_ID 1 switch jobs in the fifth month of 2017 (Job1 -> Job2). Due to the properties of the `Municipality_code`, the code will remain 1 (because at 1-2017, we had Job1 with corresponding `Municipality_code` 1). I need a piece of code that corrects the `Municipality_code` (thus, from 5/2017 we need `Municipality_code` 20 instead of 1). I tried the following piece of code, but my effort was in vain.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Person_ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(lag = lag(Job_ID, default = NA, order_by = Job_ID), 
                Municipality_corrected = if_else(Job_ID == lag, Municipality_code[1], Municipality_code[2]))
```

And the desired output...

```
Person_ID Month Year Job_ID Municipality_code  lag Municipality_corrected
1          1     1 2017   Job1                 1 <NA>                     NA
2          1     2 2017   Job1                 1 Job1                      1
3          1     3 2017   Job1                 1 Job1                      1
4          1     4 2017   Job1                 1 Job1                      1
5          1     5 2017   Job2                 1 Job1                      1
6          1     6 2017   Job2                 1 Job2                      20
7          1     7 2017   Job2                 1 Job2                      20
8          1     8 2017   Job2                 1 Job2                      20
9          1     9 2017   Job2                 1 Job2                      20
10         1    10 2017   Job2                 1 Job2                      20
11         1    11 2017   Job2                 1 Job2                      20
12         1    12 2017   Job2                 1 Job2                      20
13         1     1 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
14         1     2 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
15         1     3 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
16         1     4 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
17         1     5 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
18         1     6 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
19         1     7 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
20         1     8 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
21         1     9 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
22         1    10 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
23         1    11 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
24         1    12 2018   Job2                 20 Job2                     20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives you the corrected `Municipality_code`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Person_ID, Job_ID) %>% 
  mutate(Municipality_corrected = last(Municipality_code))

# A tibble: 24 x 6
# Groups:   Person_ID, Job_ID [2]
#    Person_ID Month  Year Job_ID Municipality_code Municipality_corrected
#        <int> <int> <int> <chr>              <int>                  <int>
#  1         1     1  2017 Job1                   1                      1
#  2         1     2  2017 Job1                   1                      1
#  3         1     3  2017 Job1                   1                      1
#  4         1     4  2017 Job1                   1                      1
#  5         1     5  2017 Job2                   1                     20
#  6         1     6  2017 Job2                   1                     20
#  7         1     7  2017 Job2                   1                     20
#  8         1     8  2017 Job2                   1                     20
#  9         1     9  2017 Job2                   1                     20
# 10         1    10  2017 Job2                   1                     20
# ... with 14 more rows
```

I use the idea, that the municipal code is the same for each job and thus group by `Job_ID`. Then I take the last `Municipality_code` for each `Job_ID` as the corrected one.

Comment: @ kath! Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I need